# "Potential Leak Error" - but I don't see it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

I'm getting a "Potential leak" message upon doing an Analyze run of this code - which works perfectly well by the way, with no errors or crashes (its just a simple UINavigationController/TableView bit.)

The full message I get is: "Potential leak of an object allocated and stored into 'tempKey'"

It doesn't make sense to me - can anyone see it?

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // create a tempKey String var, which will store the clicked-artist's name 

    // -- this here is the line the compiler says the error is in:
    NSString *tempKey = [[NSString alloc] init];


    if ([ArtisticStaffNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == @"Jeff Smith") 
        tempKey = @"Jeff";
    else if ([ArtisticStaffNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == @"Dan Jones")
        tempKey = @"Dan";
    else if ([ArtisticStaffNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == @"Matt Low")
        tempKey = @"Mat";
    else if ([ArtisticStaffNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == @"Lisa Jennings")
        tempKey = @"Lis";
    else if ([ArtisticStaffNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == @"Michael Bluarique")
        tempKey = @"Mike";

    artisticStaffDetailVC *artStaffVC = [[artisticStaffDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName: @"artisticStaffDetailVC" bundle:nil];
    artStaffVC.key = tempKey;

    [tempKey release];

    // Sets the text of the BACK button on next screen to "back":
    // alloc a UIBarButtonItem:
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
    backButton.title = @"Staff";

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [backButton release];

    // Pushes the next view/screen on:
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:artStaffVC animated:YES];
    [artStaffVC.key release];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The analyzer is correct. If you do this:

```
NSString* someString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

You have a pointer to an NSString that you own. If you then do this:

```
someString = @"Blah";
```

You have assigned `someString` to point to a *new* NSString object, and leaked the first. That line does not simply change the existing string's contents. This is exactly what you're doing with your `tempKey`.

Comment: Well I tried simply declaring 'tempKey' without 'alloc'ing it. (Meaning: ' NSString *tempKey; ' - with no 'alloc' or 'init'.) But then a few lines later, at 'artStaffVC.key = tempKey;'  I got this message: "assigned value is garbage or undefined". So I guess that wasn't the right approach.  So.... how do I fix this? What's the right way to do this?

Comment: @sirab333, it would be best to initialize the pointer to nil, instead of simply declaring it. This will theoretically prevent an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` if you try to use the string without assigning it. So try `NSString* tempKey = nil;` instead of `NSString* tempKey = [[NSString alloc] init];`.

Comment: That worked! :-)  Now just gotta figure out why and how :-)  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tool called [Instruments](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2008/01/04/objective-c-using-instruments-to-trace-messages-to-nil/) to see if you really are having a leak and where to find it.